# Conditional float formatting for amount in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, rounding, number-formatting

I am struggling to format a float number to string with conditional formatting.

```
Input : Float Number 00000.NN
Output : string 00000.NN
```

Conditions :

if a variable decimalplace = 2 the convert the number as is to string upto 2 decimal place, no rounding

if a variable decimalplace = 0 the convert the number as is to string upto 2 decimal place. Just trim the decimal part with .00

Example :

```
if decimal place = 2
    then 123456 will 123456.00
    then 123456.00 will 123456.00
    then 123456.12 will 123456.12

if decimal place = 0
    then 123456 will 123456.00
    then 123456.00 will 123456.00
    then 123456.12 will 123456.00
```

Comment: Please include what you have tried that is not working

Comment: You shouldn't be doing the formatting in your query. Formatting belongs in the presentation layer.

Comment: Do you need to round the number e.g. 123456.54 -> 123457.00?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A combination of `ROUND()` and `FORMAT()` is a possible solution:

```
DECLARE @place int = 2;

SELECT 
   [Number],
   FORMAT(ROUND([Number], @place), '#.00') AS [FormattedNumber] 
FROM (VALUES
   (123456),
   (123456.00),
   (123456.12),
   (123456.1245)
) v ([Number])
```

Answer (score 1):

Does the following provide your expected results?

```
declare @DecimalPlace tinyint = 0, @num Float = 123456.12;
select Concat(Format(@num, '#.' + Replicate('0',@DecimalPlace)), Iif(@DecimalPlace = 0, '.00',''));
```